# zip folder excluding only root directory in bash

Tags: bash, zip

What's the best way to zip a folder excluding only the root directory in bash? I am trying with `-j` option, but it excludes all the directories up to the file.

So, say I have the following structure:

```
.
├── f1
│   └── f
│       └── file
├── f2
│   └── f
│       └── file
└── f3
    └── f
        └── file
```

What I want is to end up with three zip files, in each a folder `f` containing a file `file`. I have tried bunch of different options, but all either end up in a zip file containing `f1/f/file` or `file`. The only thing that changes is how these files and folders get zipped:

**zip -r f1.zip f1/**

```
$ zip -r f1.zip f1/
  adding: f1/ (stored 0%)
  adding: f1/f/ (stored 0%)
  adding: f1/f/file (stored 0%)
$ unzip -l f1.zip 
Archive:  f1.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2023-03-15 22:13   f1/
        0  2023-03-15 22:14   f1/f/
        0  2023-03-15 22:14   f1/f/file
---------                     -------
        0                     3 files
```

**zip -r f1.zip f1/f**

```
$ zip -r f1.zip f1/f
  adding: f1/f/ (stored 0%)
  adding: f1/f/file (stored 0%)
$ unzip -l f1.zip 
Archive:  f1.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2023-03-15 22:14   f1/f/
        0  2023-03-15 22:14   f1/f/file
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files
```

With the above result I end up with `zip -r f1.zip f1/*`

And if I use the `-j` parameter I end up with only the `file`.

```
$ zip -r -j f1.zip f1/
  adding: file (stored 0%)
$ unzip -l f1.zip 
Archive:  f1.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2023-03-15 22:14   file
---------                     -------
        0                     1 file
```

I end up with the same result with `zip -r -j f1.zip f1/*`.

For now I change directory, zip it and change it back, but it seems that that has to be a better way.

```
for folder in `ls -d */`; do 
    pushd ${folder%?}; 
    zip -r ../${folder%?}.zip f/; 
    popd; 
done
```

Comment: why would there be a better way? what's wrong about what you're currently doing? It seems to both intuitively and from knowing `zip`, be the right thing to do.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Idk. it feels like going back and forth is not the right thing to do, and there is a way of achieving this just discarding the root folder.

Comment: well, but it literally describes what you want zip to do. So it's the right thing to do,.

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Does it have to be `zip` or can GNU `tar` be used instead, which creates a `.tgz`?

Comment: @Cyrus I need a zip file as it goes to aws lambda and lambda accepts only .zip

Comment: `cd f1 && zip -r ../f1.zip *` will add all excluding `.*` files; they must be added as extra param. But anyway, adding one base/root directory is always a good choice for people that will unzip the file.